# Can a Tangent Space always be expressed with “more structure” than just a vector space (e.g. a choice of basis for Stiefel manifold)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, orthogonal-matrices

I'm currently trying to read about the Stiefel manifold, or set of all $p$ orthonormal $n$-dimensional vectors embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$.
$$\mathcal{V}_p(\mathbb{R}^n) = \{U \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p} \:|\: U^T U = \mathbb{I}_p\}.$$

Thus, for any $X\in \mathcal{V}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the tangent space can be expressed (under an isomorphism) as $$T_X\mathcal{V}_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \simeq \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}.$$

However, one interesting (and useful formulation for defining the canonical inner product) is as follows:

- Let $X\in \mathcal{V}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
- Let $X_\bot \in \mathcal{V}_{n-p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be s.t. when $X^TX_\bot \equiv 0$.
- Then $$T_X\mathcal{V}_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \simeq \{XA + X_\bot B \:|\: A \text{ is skew-symmetric}\}.$$

I think the reason I'm confused is that this representation of the tangent space seems to have a “more explicit” structure than just $\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$.

Is it always true that a tangent space can be formulated in a way that has more structure than just a vector space? Or is this just a use of a convenient basis for the same vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$?

Is there always a “natural” basis to use for the tangent space?

Comment: What do you mean by "more structure"?  i.e. how do you interpret your tangent space to have "more" of something than the vector space structure?

Comment: The tangent space $T_xM$ of a $d$-dimensional manifold $M$ at a point $x$ is a $d$-dimensional vector space. But it is rarely a good idea to think of $T_xM$ as being $\mathbb R^d$, because the choice of a basis for $T_xM$ can rarely be made for all $x$ simultaneously (and depending continuously on the point $x$). Do you know about vector bundles?
Also, the dimension of the Stiefel manifold is not $np$ but rather $np-\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$.

Comment: The tangent space of an explicitly defined manifold, especially one with natural geometric symmetries, usually has additional structure implied by the geometric structure of the manifold. This starts with just the sphere, where the tangent space is the hyperplane perpendicular to the position vector. If you haven't already done so, you should look at the tangent bundles of complex projective space and Grassmannians before studying those of Stiefel manifolds.

Comment: @TomGoodwillie I see. So the tangent space can be thought of as a $np-\frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ dim. subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$. And we can explicitly define a basis for this subspace at each $T_X \mathcal{V}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ using the matrices $X$ and $X_\bot$.

I'm only vaguely familiar with vector bundles. In this context should it be thought of as the same vector space with a unique basis defined smoothly over all the tangent spaces over the Stiefel manifold? Or unique vector spaces entirely?

Comment: @DeaneYang I only have a basic background in differential geometry, but this specific manifold came up in my current research and I'm trying to understand its structure better. Do you have any introductory resources you can recommend on understanding the tangent bundle of complex projective space and Grassmanians?

Comment: @Moo Think of the case $p=1$. Then the Stiefel manifold is the ($n-1$ dimensional) unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$? Does the tangent space of the sphere at a point have an obvious basis? When $n-1=2$ there is a theorem (the "hairy ball theorem") saying that it does not have a basis depending continuously on the point.

Comment: @Tom more technically (and aesthetically) I believe one should use "Hairy sphere theorem"...

Comment: The tangent spaces to the Stiefel manifolds carry canonical actions of an orthogonal group, coming from the homogeneous space structure https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold#As_a_homogeneous_space More generally, the tangent bundle is homogeneous (and hence an associated bundle), with fibre given by a linear quotient of Lie algebras (see Prop 1.4 here https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~cap/files/Geom-Homog.pdf), with an induced adjoint action by the stabiliser group.

Comment: It's hard to find an exposition that doesn't assume a lot of knowledge. If you're comfortable with the orthogonal and unitary groups, then there are many expositions of this. I suggest googling something like "tangent space grassmannian". Doing this, I found: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.13699.pdf

Comment: I also suggest posting or migrating this question to math.stackexchange.com, where there are more people in a similar position as you, so they might be able better able to provide down-to-earth explanations.